# Add HTML to wordpress database

Tags: php, wordpress, themes

Hey, how do I insert raw HTML in Wordpress's database? I'm using add_option to add values to wp_options table of Wordpress. But Wordpress escapes everything before inserting to the database, so will it pose a problem? If so, what is the correct way

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use [addslashes](http://www.php.net/addslashes) and [stripslashes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php), like said in [Wordpress Forums](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/242413).